# pygame won't load just one image

Tags: python, image, pygame

By using pygame, I am loading up several images. They are all very similar, in size, and are all `png`s, and are all in the same folder. And, for the sake of error searching, they are all loaded in exactly the same way. However, one of them won't load, and I have no idea why.

```
player_character = PlayerCharacter('resources\player.png', 100, 700, 50, 50)
monster_character = PlayerCharacter('resources\enemy.png', 200, 700, 50, 50)
treasure_sprite = PlayerCharacter('resources\treasure.png', 300, 700, 50, 50)
```

[image: three sprites and error message]

Both the enemy, and player, images load perfectly fine. However, the treasure image won't.
The error message is odd as well as it says it can't load `reasure.png` I don't know why it is missing the 't'.

Comment: \t is a special character, being tab. Totally forgot. Thank you to the 2 answers below for pointing that out.

Comment: Please select accept one of the answers so that others will know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The \t of \treasure is being interpreted as a tab character. You can see that the t is missing in the error message which provides the clue. Put r in front of your strings to tell python that they are raw strings:

```
r’resources\treasure.png’
```

It’s worth doing this for all the images.

Comment: \t as a special character, yes that makes sense.
Perfect, wonderful. Such a newb mistake. Thanks

Comment: Both the answers will fix your problem but to do it properly you might want to look at os.path.join

Answer (score 1):

It is because your path is using a backslash `\` and `\t` in python is the special character for a tab, causing it to say tab - reasure. To fix this you can use the backslash twice \ in your path names.

```
treasure_sprite = PlayerCharacter('resources\\treasure.png', 300, 700, 50, 50)
```

The reason your other paths worked is because `\e` and `\p` don't have any special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Your code i not working because `'\t'` represents a tab **`'    '`**, see: https://www.quora.com/What-does-t-do-in-Python

so instead do:

```
r'resources\treasure.png'
```